# Error while inserting attribute table to Layout using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, print-composer, layouts

I am trying to insert a qgis attribute table to a layout using Visual Studio Code, how would I do it?

```
layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('nombre_layout')

table = QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable(layout)

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('nombre_capa')[0]
table.setVectorLayer(layer)
table.setDisplayOnlyVisibleFeatures(True)
table.setDisplayHeader(True) #This line doesn't work

layout.addLayoutItem(table)

table.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(150, 150, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
table.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```

I get the error:

> File "c:\Users\Desktop\Proyectos\PyQgis\script.py", line 174,
> in  table.setDisplayHeader(True) #This line doesn't work
> AttributeError: 'QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable' object has no attribute
> 'setDisplayHeader'

Comment: What do you expect `setDisplayHeader` to do?

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> table.setDisplayHeader(True) #This line doesn't work
> ```

Because there is no method named `setDisplayHeader` of `table`(`QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable` instance). Therefore, you don't need to use it.

You probably try to display header. Use

```
table.setHeaderMode(QgsLayoutTable.FirstFrame)
```

or

```
table.setHeaderMode(0)
```

It is set to `QgsLayoutTable.FirstFrame` by default. All options are: ([Reference](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutTable.html#aa4b5f5ea25e2e6e060f3e56a72f02078))

- `QgsLayoutTable.FirstFrame`: `0`
- `QgsLayoutTable.AllFrames`: `1`
- `QgsLayoutTable.NoHeaders`: `2`

Edit: Use `layout.addMultiFrame(table)` instead of `layout.addLayoutItem(table)`.

Comment: Ahh ok, but now have a new problem. The final line(layout.addLayoutItem(table)) show error.                                                                                                                                      'File "c:\Users\Desktop\Proyectos\PyQgis\script.py", line 185, in <module>
    layout.addLayoutItem(table)
TypeError: QgsLayout.addLayoutItem(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable'

Comment: Use `layout.addMultiFrame(table)` instead of `layout.addLayoutItem(table)`.